# NavigationViewItem is not centered

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I want to make a navigation view like Microsoft Store.

[image: Microsoft Store]

So far I have done this.

[image: My App]

But there is two problem.

1. The icon and the text is not centered.
2. The selection indicator is very small.

How can I solve this problem. Here is my xaml.

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Torrent"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
xmlns:Custom="using:System.Numerics"
x:Class="Torrent.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">


<muxc:NavigationView 
    x:Name="nvSample"
    IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="False" PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact" CompactPaneLength="80" FontSize="24" >

    <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <!--<muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Play" Content="Menu Item1" Tag="SamplePage1" />-->
        <muxc:NavigationViewItem Tag="SamplePage1" Height="80" BackgroundSizing="OuterBorderEdge">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="&#xE138;" FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="All" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </muxc:NavigationViewItem>
    </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>

    <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
</muxc:NavigationView>
```

Comment: There is a Rectangle control that was named **SelectionIndicator** in the `NavigationViewItemPresenter` of NavigationViewItem, which controls the visual of the selection indicator, so you could change its height to do this issue.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix is to use a negative left margin for the `StackPanel`:

```
<NavigationViewItem Tag="SamplePage1" Height="80" BackgroundSizing="OuterBorderEdge">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-5 0 0 0">
        <TextBlock Text="&#xE138;" ... />
        ...
```

You could adjust the value (`-5` in the sample markup above) according to your requirements and size.